# How to make simple functions max, mean, and data selection run faster in DASK than PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Recently I was learning Dask and heard that it is memory efficient and faster than pandas.

It might be memory efficient, but a simple benchmarking gives me the less speed for dask than pandas.

**Qn: HOW TO INCREASE SPEED IN DASK ?**

Here is the setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da

import time
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df = df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(100)])
print(df.shape)
df.head(2)

def benchmark(func):
    start = time.time()
    func()
    end = time.time()
    print("{0:.4f} seconds for {1}".format((end - start), func.__name__))

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=8)

def get_mean():
    return df['fare'].mean()

def get_mean_dask():
    return ddf['fare'].mean().compute()

def get_max():
    return df['fare'].max()

def get_max_dask():
    return ddf['fare'].max().compute()

def get_sum():
    return df['fare'].sum()

def get_sum_dask():
    return ddf['fare'].sum().compute()

def get_filter():
    return df[df['fare'] > 10.0]

def get_filter_dask():
    return ddf[ddf['fare'] > 10.0].compute()
```

**Testing dask vs pandas**

```
for i,func in enumerate([get_mean, get_mean_dask,
            get_max, get_max_dask,
            get_sum, get_sum_dask,
            get_filter, get_filter_dask]):
    benchmark(func)
    if (i+1) %2 == 0:
        print()
```

**Results**

```
0.0007 seconds for get_mean
0.0105 seconds for get_mean_dask

0.0006 seconds for get_max
0.0054 seconds for get_max_dask

0.0006 seconds for get_sum
0.0055 seconds for get_sum_dask

0.0022 seconds for get_filter
0.0438 seconds for get_filter_dask
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask adds overhead to whatever you are doing, of the order 50us **per task** for threads to 0.5ms for the distributed scheduler. A single calculation may consist of many tasks. To get good parallelism and speedup, and not have your total time dominated by overhead, you must have tasks which take substantially longer than the overhead. This is why Dask is aimed at big- or at least intermediate-data, which for dataframes might mean partition sizes >100MB. (this is before considering the GIL and other factors)

In short, it makes no sense to try to use Dask for something where the total time with Pandas is of the order ms or less. Where Pandas works well, use Pandas.

From 
http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html :

> For data that fits into RAM, Pandas can often be faster and easier to use than Dask DataFrame. While “Big Data” tools can be exciting, they are almost always worse than normal data tools while those remain appropriate.

Comment: Awesome!, I was overwhelmed by the concept of Dask and tried to use it everywhere. I was thinking if I use four cores rather than one core using dask, all the times results will be faster.  Was completely ignoring overhead. Thanks for the clarification. If the data fits in memory pandas is the boss.